# Incrementing Multiple Genvars in Verilog Generate Statement

Tags: hardware, syntax-error, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I'm trying to create a multi-stage comparator in verilog and I can't figure out how to increment multiple genvars in a single generate loop. I'm trying the following:

```
genvar i,j;
//Level 1
generate
  j=0;
  for (i=0;i<128;i=i+1)
  begin: level1Comp
    assign ci1[i] = minw(tc[j],tc[j+1]);
    j = j+2;
  end
endgenerate
```

And getting the following error:

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
  Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "encoder.v", 322: token is '='
    j=0;
```

Anyone know how to increment multiple genvars in the same generate statement? Or at least get equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `ci1` has half the depth of `tc` and you want, say `ci1[0] = min(tc[0], tc[1])`, `ci[1] = min(tc[2], tc[3])` etc, the following should work:

```
module st_genvar();

  int ci1 [0:127];
  int tc [0:255];

  function int minw(int i1, int i2);
      if(i1 < i2 )
        minw = i1;
      else
        minw = i2;
  endfunction

  genvar i;
  //Level 1
  generate
      for (i=0;i<128;i=i+1)
        begin: level1Comp
            assign ci1[i] = minw(tc[i*2],tc[i*2+1]);
        end
  endgenerate

endmodule
```

Answer (score 17):

> Anyone know how to increment multiple genvars in the same generate
>   statement?

This is not allowed because a generate for loop creates an implicit localparam statement for the loop variable and elaborates the items in the loop based only on that localparam. This means any items inside the loop must be valid outside the loop if the genvar was declared as a localparam.

```
genvar i,j;
//Level 1
generate
  j=0;
  for (i=0;i<128;i=i+1)
  begin: level1Comp
    assign ci1[i] = minw(tc[j],tc[j+1]);
    j = j+2;
  end
endgenerate
```

becomes

```
//Done for each value of i
genvar j;
localparam integer i = i_for_each_iteration;

j=0; //Not valid outside a procedural context so modelsim complains
assign ci1[i] = minw(tc[j],tc[j+1]);
j = j+2; //Also not valid outside a procedural context
```

In this case you could create a 'constant' value dependent on the genvar using an explicit parameter inside the loop.

```
genvar i;
//Level 1
generate
  for (i=0;i<128;i=i+1)
  begin: level1Comp
    localparam integer j = i*2;
    assign ci1[i] = minw(tc[j],tc[j+1]);
  end
endgenerate
```

Comment: very interesting! Does the localparam create something in hardware?

Comment: No. Localparams are constants that are used for design elaboration.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The answer that was accepted may have solved the OP's problem, but this answer actually answered the OP's question. I found myself with the same question and this helped me. Thanks.

Comment: this means we can do only two level loop using this scheme? (I mean, generate loop and localparam).