# Conditional instantiation of verilog module

Tags: conditional-statements, instantiation, verilog, hdl

Is it possible to instantiate a module conditionally in verliog ?

example :

```
if (en==1)  
  then module1 instantiation  
else  
  module2 instantiation
```

Answer (score 25):

From IEEE Std 1364-2001 :

> 12.1.3.3 generate-conditional A generate-conditional is an if-else-if generate construct that permits modules, user defined primitives,
>   Verilog gate primitives, continuous assignments, initial blocks and
>   always blocks to be conditionally instantiated into another module
>   based on an expression that is deterministic at the time the design is
>   elaborated.

example given in LRM :

```
module multiplier(a,b,product);
parameter a_width = 8, b_width = 8;
localparam product_width = a_width+b_width; // can not be modified
// directly with the defparam statement
// or the module instance statement #
input [a_width-1:0] a;
input [b_width-1:0] b;
output [product_width-1:0] product;

generate
    if((a_width < 8) || (b_width < 8))
        CLA_multiplier #(a_width,b_width) u1(a, b, product);
        // instantiate a CLA multiplier
    else
        WALLACE_multiplier #(a_width,b_width) u1(a, b, product);
        // instantiate a Wallace-tree multiplier
endgenerate
// The generated instance name is u1

endmodule
```

Comment: Generate statements are used to define/describe hardware at compile time. They are synthesizable for the given configuration.

Answer (score 5):

You can use compiler directives like

```
`define FOO
`ifdef FOO
    module1 ...
`else
    module2 ...
`endif
```

to choose an instantiation at compile time.

If in you are asking if you can instantiate a module based on a wire value, no you cannot do that.

Answer (score 5):

You can not do this at runtime as you are describing hardware, which can not be changed on the fly. You may enable or disable a feature to save power but you can not make it stop existing. Assuming you are looking to improve the reuse or configure-ability of blocks:

Pre compiler techniques are often used as well as the ``defines` (tick defines) Tim mentions.

They would consist of a Perl, ruby etc script which parses a template file.

[My Previous answer using ruby scripts and templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532997/97073).