# Using multiple genvar in Verilog loop

Tags: for-loop, syntax, syntax-error, verilog

Is It possible using different "genvar" in a loop? Is there an alternative mode to realize it?

I try with this example:

```
genvar i;
genvar j;
genvar k;

generate 
    k=0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1) 
    begin: firstfor
            for (j = 0; j < N; j = j + 1)
            begin: secondfor
                if(j>i) 
                begin 
                    assign a[i+j*N] = in[i] && p[k];
                    k=k+1;      
                end
            end
    end 
endgenerate
```

And when I run "Check Syntax" display this error:

```
Syntax error near "=". (k=k+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this question because unless very familiar with generates it looks like it should work, however there is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9561762/97073) which tries to use an extra genvar.

The syntax is not allowed because of how the generates are unrolled. Integers can only be used inside always/initial processes.

If it is just combinatorial wiring rather than parametrised instantiation you might be able to do what you need just using integers (I would not normally recommend this):

```
integer i;
integer j;
integer k;

localparam N = 2;
reg [N*N:0] a ;
reg [N*N:0] in ;
reg [N*N:0] p ;

always @* begin 
  k=0;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1) begin: firstfor
    for (j = 0; j < N; j = j + 1) begin: secondfor
      if(j>i) begin 
        a[i+j*N] = in[i] && p[k];
        k=k+1;      
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure how synthesis will like this but the assignments are static, it might work.

Comment: Morgan -- I just added an answer here.   I am inexperienced in creating Verilog and wonder about the practical implications in avoiding `always @*` -- other than "hey, neat trick" is it necessary/useful?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to avoid `always @*` when you want to do more advanced math with `genvar` loops.  Use `localparam` and a `function`.

Make `k` a `localparam` derived from the genvars with a function, and use `k` as originally intended.

The `getk` function seems to violate the principles of code reuse by basically recreating the loops from the `generate` block, but `getk` allows each unrolled loop iteration to derive the immutable localparam `k` from genvars `i` and `j`.  There is no separate accumulating variable `k` that is tracked across all the unrolled loops.  Both `iverilog` and `ncvlog` are happy with this.

(Note that the original example could optimize with `j=i+1` as well, but there is still an issue with deriving `k`.)

```
module top();

localparam N=4;

function automatic integer getk;
  input integer istop;
  input integer jstop;
  integer i,j,k;
  begin
    k=0;
    for (i=0; i<=istop; i=i+1) begin: firstfor
      for (j=i+1; j<((i==istop)? jstop : N); j=j+1) begin: secondfor
        k=k+1;
      end
    end
    getk=k;
  end
endfunction

genvar i,j;
generate
  for (i = 0; i < N; i = i + 1) begin: firstfor
    for (j = i+1; j < N; j = j + 1) begin: secondfor
      localparam k = getk(i,j);           
      initial $display("Created i=%0d j=%0d k=%0d",i,j,k);
    end
  end
endgenerate

endmodule
```

Output:

```
$ iverilog tmptest.v 
$ ./a.out
Created i=0 j=1 k=0
Created i=0 j=2 k=1
Created i=0 j=3 k=2
Created i=1 j=2 k=3
Created i=1 j=3 k=4
Created i=2 j=3 k=5
```

I discovered the 'trick' of using functions to derive values from the genvars here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53327/generate-gate-with-a-parametrized-number-of-inputs

Comment: I think this is a better solution, for generating static values (localparam). if you wanted to create an assignment mapping ie combinatorial logic you would need the `assign` or `always @*`.

Comment: @Morgan - thanks.  I have done mostly schematic->structural verilog work.  I am playing with `generate` because I have a schematic-oriented mindset.  But I think I'm overusing it, and creating too-elaborate structure (hierarchy+wires) for combinatorial functionality that can be simpler with an `always` and a specific sensitivity list.