# Verilog - increment local parameter in generate block

Tags: parameters, verilog, increment

I'm getting an error in my Verilog generate block, on the line where it says j = j+1; stating `j is an unknown type'

```
genvar i;
generate
    localparam integer j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < BUFFER; i=i+1) begin
        if((i%DATA_WIDTH) < (KERNEL_SIZE-1)) begin
            assign o_input_matrix[((j+1)*DATA_WIDTH)-1:j*DATA_WIDTH] = 
buffer[((i+1)*DATA_WIDTH)-1:i*DATA_WIDTH];
            j = j+1;
        end
    end
endgenerate
```

BUFFER, DATA_WIDTH, and KERNEL_SIZE are local parameters I have in my module.

I've been looking at ways I could have a 2nd parameter in my generate block, I've found out that I can only use genvar variables in a for loop, so I couldnt make a 2nd genvar variable for j.

I came across this question:
[Incrementing Multiple Genvars in Verilog Generate Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561762/incrementing-multiple-genvars-in-verilog-generate-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I tried basing my code of the 2nd answer, but my situation is slightly different because I'm only incrementing it in an if statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to make a function to define the value of `j`.

```
genvar i;
for (i = 0; i < BUFFER; i=i+1)
   if((i%DATA_WIDTH) < (KERNEL_SIZE-1)) begin
      localparam j = func(i);
      assign o_input_matrix[((j+1)*DATA_WIDTH)-1:j*DATA_WIDTH] = 
buffer[((i+1)*DATA_WIDTH)-1:i*DATA_WIDTH];
        end
    end
function integer func(integer ii);
   for (ii = 0;ii < BUFFER; ii++)
     if ((ii %DATA_WIDTH) < (KERNEL_SIZE-1)) ii++;
endfunction
```

Didn't try this, but hope it gets you close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @dave_59, I think I managed to use a function to do the mapping I need.
It's difficult for me to test whether this solution works, as I am getting a runtime error, is there any way to display the parameters in the generate block? I tried using $display, but I don't think I can use it in a generate block.

Comment: I don't know how a generate block would jive you a runtime error? What does it say? You can put `initial $display(parameters)` inside the generate assuming that comes before your runtime error. (SystemVerilog allows you to put $info as an elaboration message)